# Binding data JSON SAPUI5 (Tiles Menu)

Tags: javascript, json, xml, sapui5

I want to binding tiles menu, but I have a problem with binding selection. I have a JSON structure:

```
{
        "module":{
            "module":[
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "name": "Kepesertaan"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Layanan dan Manfaat"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Investasi"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Perbendaharaan"
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "Aktuaria"
                }               
            ],

            "system":[
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Pengumuman"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
    onInit: function(oEvent){
        var oModel = new JSONModel("metroui/module.json");
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },

    pressTileModule : function(oEvent){
        var sPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var oContext = oModel.getProperty(sPath); 
    }
```

XML:

```
<core:View  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
            xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
            xmlns="sap.m"
            xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
            xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt"
            controllerName="metroui.MetroUI" 
            xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <App id="navCon">
                <pages>
                    <Page id="module" showHeader="false">
                        <Panel headerText="Module">
                            <content>
                                <l:HorizontalLayout
                                    id="TileContainerModule"
                                    allowWrapping="true"
                                    content="{/}">
                                        <GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" 
                                            header="{name}" press="pressTileModule">
                                            <tileContent>
                                                <TileContent>
                                                    <content>
                                                        <ImageContent description="{id}" src="sap-icon://list"/>
                                                    </content>
                                                </TileContent>
                                            </tileContent>
                                        </GenericTile>
                                </l:HorizontalLayout>
                            </content>  
                        </Panel>    
                    </Page>
                </pages>
            </App>      
</core:View>
```

for binding object module>module (from JSON), set in XML file in content="{/module/module}" but I want set content path JSON **in controller** because I want set conditional binding, sometimes I want just binding module>module or binding module>system (from JSON structure). How to binding selection when I load JSON file? If I put JSON structure in controller, I can create new JSON model this.module.module or this.module.system and I set content="{/}" in XML, but I can't selection binding when I load file JSON. How to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

Step 1. In onInit() , Get the json object using 
`var jsonData = $.getJSON("metroui/module.json");`

Step 2. Check if the jsonData has 'module' or 'system' using 
`If ('module' in jsonData.module)`